# How do I import this JSON into 2 separate tables?

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, import

I'm working with the set of data at this endpoint: https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php

I need to take this JSON and import it into 2 tables: `Cards` and `Sets`. Below is the schema for each table.

**Cards**

```
id
name
type
desc
race
archetype
atk
def
ban_tcg
ban_ocg
ban_goat
level
attribute
linkval
image_url
image_url_small
pendulum_scale
linkmarker_topleft --deeper than single level
linkmarker_top --deeper than single level
linkmarker_topright --deeper than single level
linkmarker_left --deeper than single level
linkmarker_right --deeper than single level
linkmarker_bottomleft --deeper than single level
linkmarker_bottom --deeper than single level
linkmarker_bottomright --deeper than single level
```

For the `Cards` table, I can insert any single level data into a table using the code below, but how do I go one level deeper into the `linkmarkers` node and return the value found into the correct column? For example, for row 8614 in the dataset, the `linkmarkers` node has only 1 key and its value is "Top", so I would need the script to insert "Top" into the `linkmarker_top` column and null for all the other `linkmarker` columns.

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
Declare @JSON2 varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\YGOCards.json', SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT @JSON2 = value 
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
select * into #cards
from openjson(@JSON2)
with (
    [id] nvarchar(4000)
    , [name] nvarchar(1000)
    , [type] nvarchar(1000)
    , [desc] nvarchar(1000)
    , [race] nvarchar(1000)
    , [archetype] nvarchar(1000)
    , [atk] nvarchar(1000)
    , [def] nvarchar(1000)
    , [ban_tcg] nvarchar(1000)
    , [ban_ocg] nvarchar(1000)
    , [ban_goat] nvarchar(1000)
    , [level] nvarchar(1000)
    , [attribute] nvarchar(1000)
    , [linkval] nvarchar(1000)
)
```

*Example output row:*

```
id ...   linkmarker_topleft  linkmarker_top  linkmarker_topright  linkmarker_left...
94259633 null                Top             null                 null
```

**Sets**

```
id
set_name
set_code
set_rarity
set_rarity_code
```

For the `Sets` table, I want to basically create a table where I relate each `id` to the `card_set` where each card came from, but I'm not sure how to do this. So using the first row of the dataset as an example:

*Example output row:*

```
id        set_name              set_code    set_rarity...
34541863  Force of the Breaker  FOTB-EN043  Common
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `linkmarkers`, you can pull it out as a JSON array, then inside a `CROSS APPLY` you can shred it using `OPENJSON` and pivot it.

For the `card_sets` array, you can `CROSS APPLY` it from the original `cards` array, and thereby pull out the `cards.id` at the same time. This can become the foreign key of your table.

```sql
SELECT
  c.*,
  lm.*
INTO #cards
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.data')
  WITH (
    [id] int
    , [name] nvarchar(1000)
    , [type] nvarchar(1000)
    , [desc] nvarchar(1000)
    , [race] nvarchar(1000)
    , [archetype] nvarchar(1000)
    , [atk] nvarchar(1000)
    , [def] nvarchar(1000)
    , [ban_tcg] nvarchar(1000)
    , [ban_ocg] nvarchar(1000)
    , [ban_goat] nvarchar(1000)
    , [level] nvarchar(1000)
    , [attribute] nvarchar(1000)
    , [linkval] nvarchar(1000)
    , linkmarkers nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
       MIN(CASE WHEN mark.value = 'Top'          THEN 1 END) [Top]
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN mark.value = 'Top-Left'     THEN 1 END) [Top-Left]
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN mark.value = 'Top-Right'    THEN 1 END) [Top-Right]
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN mark.value = 'Bottom'       THEN 1 END) [Bottom]
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN mark.value = 'Bottom-Left'  THEN 1 END) [Bottom-Left]
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN mark.value = 'Bottom-Right' THEN 1 END) [Bottom-Right]
    FROM OPENJSON(c.linkmarkers) mark
) lm;

  
SELECT
  c.id card_id,
  s.*
INTO #sets
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.data')
  WITH (
    [id] int,
    card_sets nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.card_sets)
  WITH (
    set_name nvarchar(100),
    set_code nvarchar(10),
    set_rarity nvarchar(100),
    set_rarity_code nvarchar(10)
  ) s;
```

Note the following:

- You can do the same thing for the other inner arrays.
- Use of JSON path to jump straight to `$.data`.
- If you need to get the array position you can use `OPENJSON` without a `WITH` schema, which gives you the array index of each object.
- Better choice of data types.
- Ideally you would create fixed tables with primary and foreign keys, rather than inserting into `#` temp tables.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02ef5a02ea9e09009df0479790afb927)

Comment: I don't see how I then get the linkmaker values into a single row in the cards table.

Comment: Good point, have modified

Answer (score -1):

Here is my logic (with javascript) for insert record into card table:

1. Grep all record
2. If `linkmarkers` found, add new field name save the record
3. Insert record

Sample Code:

```
const jp = require('jsonpath')
const source = require("./source.js") // reference from cardinfo.php

async function main() {
  // Cards
  let query = jp.query(source, "$.data[*]")
  query = query.map((x) => {
    if(x.linkmarkers){
      (x.linkmarkers).forEach((y) => {
        console.log(`linkmarker_${y.toLowerCase()}`)
        x[`linkmarker_${y.toLowerCase()}`] = y
      })      
    }
    return x
  })

  // Set Table
  let table = [["id", "nams", "linkmarket_topleft", "linkmarket_top", "linkmarker_bottom"]]
  for(let i=0; i<query.length; i++){
    let { id, name, linkmarket_topleft, linkmarket_top, linkmarker_bottom } = query[i]
    
    // Your insert SQL query
    // ...
  }
}
main()
```

Result in csv after point 2:
[image]

Comment: I was looking for a SQL solution, but this is helpful for anyone who wants a js solution